# What does the error message "The smart card is not fully personalized for use" mean?

Tags: windows-10, smartcard

Cannot upload any key to the smart card, due to the following error message. Changing the pin on smartcard works...

[image: error message received on all smart card actions]

The message is seemingly issued by the smartcardcredentialprovider.dll

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issues and realised I missed the `/generate` suffix within the syntax. I deleted the initial card using `tpmvscmgr.exe destroy /instance ROOT\SMARTCARDREADER\0000` and then recreated correctly.

All outlined within [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/virtual-smart-card-tpmvscmgr)